# Dropbox datastore

Tags: web-access, memoization

[Dropbox seems to have a feature where it can be used as a database.](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore)

This would be really cool to use for memoized functions, that can be restored
on several computers and sessions.

I have a function that is hard to compute, but the output is always just a natural number, and I wish to make Mathematica remember all computed values, between sessions and both at home and at work.

*Has anyone tried this solution? What other options are there?*

I think that a database or something similar is a must; a plain-text file in a Dropbox folder can be corrupted if the program crashes during writing, and it is tricky to know when to update the file.

Comment: If you have V10 then Dropbox is [supported](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Dropbox.html) out the box, so it shouldn't be too hard. But the Wolfram Cloud, i.e. [CloudPut](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudPut.html), is a more natural option I think.

Comment: Of course it has it built-in, haha. 
Too bad my office only have V9. But the dropbox API is different from the Mathematica functions, which only work with files...

Comment: Come to think of it, you can probably use Pastebin as I did [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1354/731). Their API lets you do the three basic things you might want to do: create a new data file, delete a data file and list all data files. (It's not the optimal database solution of course, but besides that...)

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, can you give details on your corruption worries and "when to update"? Have you had issues using `Import`/`Export`? We use Dropbox and Google apps, like Gsheets for online coediting, with Mathematica with no problems. Dataset size on the order of 250m `LeafCount`.

Comment: I was more thinking along the line of memoization, but storing computed things in the database also.
Thing is, if I run a batch for computing a large set of polynomials, say, and the kernel crashes, all partial results are lost. If I append to a raw file, the file handler is still open, so there might be data loss. Besides, I think import/export on EVERY new result computed, is a bit tough on the hard-drive (and also slows down the computation immensely), although I suppose writing to a remote location is even slower...