# How to share a notebook?

Tags: export, notebooks, wolfram-cloud, deployment

I have a folder in dropbox syncing to my desktop. I tried sharing a notebook file this way, but this generates lots of errors, conflicts, and data loss:

[image]

I have notebooks with Dynamic and other functionalities that the Wolfram Cloud does not support. Also, I don't want to make my friends sign up and/or pay for the Wolfram cloud service.

Is there any better solution out there for co-authoring notebooks?

Related:

- [Dropbox datastore](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60921/dropbox-datastore)

Comment: A [Dropbox badge] (https://www.dropbox.com/help/7672) for Mathematica would not bring @MarcoB version control, but could it eliminate some of the errors you see?

Comment: @Christopher the Dropbox badge is interesting, but in order for it to work, Dropbox would essentially have to implement versioning for MMA notebooks...

Answer (score 14):

I have no personal experience with versioning/sharing in *Mathematica* yet, but my group and I have come to the point where we have to consider these options, so I have been looking around a bit. I can't say that I have any definitive answer, but this is what I've learned from perusing this community's archive.

First of all, in order to share *Mathematica* contents among multiple users that may need to modify the code, you need some form of version control software. I noticed that you had previously asked another question along these lines a few years ago ([How can I set up a versioning system within a notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6435/27951)), to which you provided an answer yourself.

Unfortunately, the consensus seems to be that **notebooks are eminently unsuited to versioning**: they contain a lot of metadata, presentation rules, information that is relevant only to the front end, etc.

A **better approach seems to be to use *.m files** to store the plain source code, and version those. There are a few examples of settings of Git that are compatible with *.m files from this site, linked below. This is probably what I personally will have to do (as soon as I gather the courage!). I don't know whether this is really suitable for the application you have in mind though.

In any case, I'll share a few posts from this site that I have saved up because I had found them interesting with respect to versioning / sharing / team collaborations:

- [Recommended settings for git when using with Mathematica projects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26174/27951), especially @TheToad's comprehensive answer there.
- [Are there suitable versioning systems for Mathematica notebooks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11258/27951)
- [Getting serious about Mathematica programming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29094/27951)
- [How to setup Team Development for a Mathematica project?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5789/27951)